# How Mat() works on dilate?

Tags: java, python, opencv, matrix

I'm working with an OpenCV Java code, and I have a problem: the method dilate needs a matrix so it can perform the transform, but what kind of matrix returns Mat() when it doesn't have any parameters?
I know that in Python you define a matrix with cv2.getStructuringElement or numpy, but I don't understand this type of call. Here's an example, any suggestions? Thanks!

```
Imgproc.dilate(cannyImg, cannyImg, new Mat());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument of `Imgproc.findContours` is the `hierachy`. If you don´t need the `hierachy` information you can just give an empty Mat to the function using `new Mat()`.

If you want to use the information you could use the function like this:

```
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(Img, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST,   Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

**Following your Edit:**

If you give dilate an empty Mat as Element using `new Mat()` it defaults to a 3x3 rectangular Element as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#void%20cvDilate%28const%20CvArr*%20src,%20CvArr*%20dst,%20IplConvKernel*%20element,%20int%20iterations%29):

> element – structuring element used for dilation; if element=Mat() , a
>   3 x 3 rectangular structuring element is used.

Comment: I realized that the question is not correct, as I was referring to other method, dilate, thanks anyway!!

Comment: It worked, thanks! I tried to look in the documentation, but I didn't find it before, ups!